# Using MSTest, xUnit or NUnit with dotnet core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, mstest

TLDR - Jump to the answer for details on a working xUnit or MSTest setup. xUnit was the least painful option.

I've been unable to get NUnit working on my build server so I've resorted to trying both xUnit and MSTest - Neither have worked for me.

MSTest I just dont get - I expected this to work but when I try to install dotnet-test-mstest from nuget I get dependency issues as all of it's dependent libraries are not compatible for netcoreapp1 for example....

The dependency MSTest.ObjectModel 1.0.1-preview does not support framework .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.

The dependency MSTest.TestAdapter.Dotnet 1.0.4-preview does not support framework.

Can anyone offer any advice on why this could be happening?

Comment: you need to show the error you get and your project json otherwise one can only speculate. On top of that - if you go to NuGet https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSTest.TestAdapter.Dotnet/ you will see: "The owner has unlisted this package. This could mean that the package is deprecated or shouldn't be used anymore." - so I guess this might be a part of your problem.

Comment: I can't really provide anymore - the error messages are in my original description. I'm just creating an empty project and it happens. The key issue seems to be that it doesn't install at all. I am wondering if Microsoft haven't upgraded the test framework in line with everything else. Online info is sparse and very difficult to isolate across versions.

Comment: I also saw the unlisted message and I think you may be right,  but it doesn't Indicate what to do instead.

Comment: This: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/05/30/announcing-mstest-framework-support-for-net-core-rc2-asp-net-core-rc2/ tells me you should not have direct references to MSTest.ObjectModel or MSTest.TestAdapter.Dotnet  in your project.json but only a reference to MSTest.TestFramework. I can see the latest version https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSTest.TestFramework/1.0.5-preview shipped a few days ago. Have you tried this one? As a side note - Asp.NET Core framework projects (https://github.com/aspnet) are using xUnit.

Comment: I don't have direct references. The error occurs when adding dotnet-test-mstest as the incompatible packages are dependencies of that. MStest.Framework on its own is no good, you need dotnet-test-mstest to be able to run the tests.

Comment: I am simultaneously looking at xUnit. I was unable to get any test discovery working with xUnit. I got NUnit working locally but it doesn't give any results in VSTS. I'm currently hammering at all 3 to find a workable solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to get this working by creating brand new projects following these instructions...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/testing/using-mstest-on-windows

It seems that MSTest dotnet core projects need to be created as console applications to work..?

In the aim of helping all others, here's the project.json that I ended up with.

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "testRunner": "mstest",

    "dependencies": {
        "dotnet-test-mstest": "1.1.1-preview",
        "MyLibrary": {
            "target": "project"
        },
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
            "type": "platform",
            "version": "1.0.1"
        },
        "MSTest.TestFramework": "1.0.4-preview",
        "NSubstitute": "2.0.0-rc"
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "netcoreapp1.0": {
            "imports": "dnxcore50"
        }
    }
}
```

I seem to be doing 2 key things differently. For a start my key dependency was previously...

```
"NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
```

while in the new project.json it is

```
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
        "type": "platform",
         "version": "1.0.1"
     }
```

(in the original project.json this was placed in the frameworks section of the file as a subdependency).

the other is in the imports section under 'newtcoreapp1.0'. In the original project.json I used this included itself, whereas the working one imports dnxcore50 (although I'm still not convinced this is actually right).

It appears that there is a bug with 1.0.5-preview of MSTest.TestFramework - I ended up changing the version for an earlier one. With 1.0.5 the tests would load but every one would fail with an error...

Could not load type 'LogMessageHandler' from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework

I looked around for somewhere to submit this as a bug but no luck yet. If anyone finds this with the same problems and knows where to log it please let me know and I'll '+1' it.

For completeness, here's a project.json file that works for NUnit (although it's NUnit 3 and reading it's output files is (at time of writing) an issue on VSTS...

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "MyLibrary": {
            "target": "project"
        },
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
        "NUnit": "3.5.0",
        "dotnet-test-nunit": "3.4.0-beta-1"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "netcoreapp1.0": {
            "imports": [
                "netcoreapp1.0",
                "portable-net45+win8"
            ],
            "dependencies": {
                "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
                    "version": "1.0.1-*",
                    "type": "platform"
                },
                "NSubstitute": "2.0.0-rc"
            }
        }
    },
    "testRunner": "nunit",
    "version": "1.0.0-*"
}
```

And here's xUnit - I'll be playing with that a bit more as it seems more viable on VSTS...

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "buildOptions": {
        "debugType": "portable"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives": "4.1.1",
        "xunit": "2.1.0",
        "dotnet-test-xunit": "1.0.0-rc2-build10015",
        "NSubstitute": "2.0.0-rc",
        "MyLibrary": {
            "target": "project"
        }

    },
    "testRunner": "xunit",
    "frameworks": {
        "netcoreapp1.0": {
            "dependencies": {
                "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
                    "type": "platform",
                    "version": "1.0.1"
                }
            },
            "imports": [
                "dotnet5.4",
                "portable-net451+win8"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

More really useful xUnit info here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/testing/unit-testing-with-dotnet-test

Overall I found,  once taking getting VSTS working as well into account,  that xUnit was far and above the easiest option to use - you just have to set up the build server tasks to use dotnet test command line and then use a publish test files task to show the results. After much pain I still couldn't get the MS test run to pass on the build server.

Comment: You are absolutely right about 1.0.5-preview of MSTest.TestFramework.  I changed it to 1.0.4 as you said and it all works fine.  I don't understand why there are no correct documentation about .Net Core?  Some examples and codes on their sites are not working at all in other area too.  This tutorial said we need to use 'Library' not 'Console Application'.

Comment: I highly recommend using xUnit if it's an option,  it was far less painful than trying to get MStest.Framework working in the end. It has the added benefit of being cross platform.

Comment: I also second @TTCG 's comment. Had the same issue

Answer (score 2):

The issue with dotnet-test-mstest 1.1.1-preview and MSTest.TestFramework 1.0.5-preview that @TTCG brought up has hence been fixed with a later release. Feel free to try this out on dotnet-test-mstest 1.1.2-preview and MSTest.TestFramework 1.0.6-preview.

Comment: upgrading dotnet-test-mstest to 1.1.2-preview fixed the issue. thanks!